# how do i restart a single website on IIS onWindows server 2003?

Tags: iis

I know I can restart all the websites on a server by typing IISRESET at the command line.
And I know that in later versions of IIS I can stop and start a single application pool
but I cant figure out how to do this on my WIndows 2003 server.
Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the identifier for the site you want to start/stop:

[image]

Then, in a command prompt:

```
cscript //nologo C:\Inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs start_server w3svc/IDENTIFIER
cscript //nologo C:\Inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs stop_server w3svc/IDENTIFIER
```

Comment: I get path requested could not be found. Err number: -2147024893 (0x80070003)  Error trying to open the object w3svc/$1443837079

Comment: Try without the $ sign. Sorry, I didn't clarify that very well.

Comment: Thank you, success at last! The stop and go icons in the GUI work as well

Comment: Uuuhhh, yes, I didn't mention that because somehow I assumed you were looking for a way to do it from the command-line only. :-/

Answer (score 1):

If the application has its own application pool, select the application pool and stop/start it from there. This can be done by going into the IIS Manager.

https://forums.iis.net/t/1210649.aspx?How+to+stop+only+one+application+not+a+entire+website+on+IIS